# Usei o código do link abaixo, e o este código abaixo. Porém ele não salva o título das linhas do Jtable, como salvar os titulos das linhas?

Tags: java, jtable

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187639/jtable-with-titled-rows-and-columns

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Report Print");

    MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page[0,number,integer]");
    try {
        table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);
   }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "Unable to Print");
    }
```

Comment: Poste seu código completo, esse pedaço não faz sentido algum. E explique mais detalhadamente o que pretende fazer.

Comment: Eu usei o código do link, por que preciso de títulos tanto nas linhas como  nas colunas, tbm preciso de certa forma gravar a matriz o problema é, não tem como grava matriz usando o código acima porque o títulos das linhas não aparecem no modo gravado exemplo pdf. Não vou postar meu código inteiro porque esta com muita coisa dentro e o projeto é muito grande. Entenda que eu usei o código do link e para exportar a matriz usei o código baixo

Comment: Sinceramente, não entendi nada.

Comment: Eu preciso criar uma tabela certo? usei o Jtable e o código do link por que preciso colocar uma identificação tanto nas colunas como nas linhas. Usei o código que está descrito acima para salvar a matriz, porém o código salva a matriz mas não salva a identificação das linhas, quero saber como faz para salvar a identificação da linhas tbm

Comment: Rodei aqui e fica exatamente como está lá na resposta.  Nao estou entendendo o que quer dizer com identificação de matriz, sendo q não há nenhuma no código.